# maven, eclipse and the filter

Tags: eclipse, maven

I use Maven to manage my project.

I find **`<properties>`** tag very useful but there's a issue with this.

When I deploy my sources to Tomcat, I should put **`/target/classes`** into Deployment Assembly to get converted resources.

example ) 
[image]
I think this above is right.

---

[image]
But I have to put **`/target/classes/`** to get converted properties.

**Spring bean example)**

```
<!-- Database -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.classname}" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="${database.defaultAutoCommit}" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${database.testWhileIdle}" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${database.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database1.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database1.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database1.password}" />
    </bean>
```

This pure variables just copied into Tomcat's webapp if I don't put **`/target/classes/`**

even though it works, this drives me crazy because Eclipse sometimes says **`"sources are not sychronized!"`**

---

**pom.xml**

```
...
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                <targetPath>${basedir}/target/webapp</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${basedir}/target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <filters>
            <filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/spring-common-bean-context.xml</filter>
            <filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/byto.cyoz.properties</filter>
        </filters>
...
```

Comment: The second screenshot seems strange to me. I bet you have all of your classes in the WEB-INF/classes and also at the root of the war. You should not add the target/classes to the assembly as eclipse should filter the resources for you. In which folder are you spring files?

Comment: they're contained in /src/main/resources and <resources> tag move them into classes folder

Comment: could you please add the plugin configuration you've added to filter the resources?

Comment: yes, I can do it right now. please check it out.

Comment: Try to remove `<targetPath>${basedir}/target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>`. There is no reason to specify the target as you are respecting the convention. (If it works I'll write a complete answer)